# Sharing a Windows network share via another server

Tags: windows, network-share

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
Server A -------> Server B\Share ------> Server C\Share
```

I would like to share a Windows network share exposed on server C by creating a "bridge" Windows share on server B so that Server A can gain access to it.

Does anyone know how to do this on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: You can't share a share through an intermediate server.

Comment: Is there any way we could do port forwarding, or something similar?